# Poner un switch en un viewHolder - Lista Personalizada en Android Studio

Tags: android, android-studio

Vengo creando una APP, una lista personalizada que se infla con datos de una WebService, como ven uno de sus campos es estado, pero esta te lo devuelve en numero (0,1,2) lo que yo quiero hacer es ponerlo en "VACANTE", "OCUPADO","RESERVADO" y eso lo logro mediante un `switch` , pero no se como aplicarlo

Esos datos lo jalo desde una WebService PHP
Este es mi codigo actual:

```
public class MetaAdapter extends RecyclerView.Adapter<MetaAdapter.MetaViewHolder>
        implements ItemClickListener {

    /**
     * Lista de objetos {@link Meta} que representan la fuente de datos
     * de inflado
     */
    private List<Plaza> items;

    /*
    Contexto donde actua el recycler view
     */
    private Context context;


    public MetaAdapter(List<Plaza> items, Context context) {
        this.context = context;
        this.items = items;
    }

    @Override
    public int getItemCount() {
        return items.size();
    }

    @Override
    public MetaViewHolder onCreateViewHolder(ViewGroup viewGroup, int i) {
        View v = LayoutInflater.from(viewGroup.getContext())
                .inflate(R.layout.item_list, viewGroup, false);
        return new MetaViewHolder(v, this);
    }

    @Override
    public void onBindViewHolder(MetaViewHolder viewHolder, int i) {
        viewHolder.nivel.setText(items.get(i).getNivel());
        viewHolder.estado.setText(items.get(i).getEstado());
        viewHolder.colegio.setText(items.get(i).getIe());
        viewHolder.especialidad.setText(items.get(i).getEspecialidad());
        viewHolder.codigo.setText(items.get(i).getCodigoPlaza());
    }


    /**
     * Sobrescritura del método de la interfaz {@link ItemClickListener}
     *
     * @param view     item actual
     * @param position posición del item actual
     */
    @Override
    public void onItemClick(View view, int position) {
        DetailActivity.launch(
                (Activity) context, items.get(position).getPlazaID());
    }


    public static class MetaViewHolder extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder
            implements View.OnClickListener {
        // Campos respectivos de un item
        public TextView nivel;
        public TextView estado;
        public TextView colegio;
        public TextView especialidad;
        public TextView codigo;
        public ItemClickListener listener;


        public MetaViewHolder(View v, ItemClickListener listener) {
            super(v);
            nivel = (TextView) v.findViewById(R.id.nivel);
            estado = (TextView) v.findViewById(R.id.estado);
            colegio = (TextView) v.findViewById(R.id.colegio);
            especialidad = (TextView) v.findViewById(R.id.especialidad);
            codigo = (TextView) v.findViewById(R.id.codigo);
            this.listener = listener;
            v.setOnClickListener(this);
        }

        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            listener.onItemClick(v, getAdapterPosition());
        }
    }
}


interface ItemClickListener {
    void onItemClick(View view, int position);
}
```

**Actualmente en mi aplicativo se ve asi :**

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Si no me equivoco, cuando rellenas el TextView estado es en esta línea:

```
viewHolder.estado.setText(items.get(i).getEstado());
```

Para poder mostrar un texto dependiendo del estado, deberías sustituir esa línea por esto:

```
switch(items.get(i).getEstado())
{
    case 0: 
        viewHolder.estado.setText("VACANTE");
        break;
    case 1: 
        viewHolder.estado.setText("OCUPADO");
        break;
    case 2: 
        viewHolder.estado.setText("RESERVADO");
        break;
    default:
        viewHolder.estado.setText("ERROR");
}
```

He añadido el default por seguridad pero si estás seguro de que NUNCA va a tomar un valor distinto a 0, 1 o 2 no tienes porqué ponerlo.

Comenta si te funciona o no y si no te funciona di que pasa.

Comment: Muchas gracias por la rapida respuesta, Me sirvio de mucho muchas gracias, por ende lo marque como voto positivo, espero mi voto favor para que mas adelante le sirva a alguien más, Gracias